# Использование параметров в подключаемом файле jsp

Tags: java, jsp

Добрый день! Хочу подключать заготовку новости в цикле.

```
<% for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { %>
     <%@include file="main_news.jsp" %>
<% } %>
```

Внутри main_news.jsp хочу сделать так:

```
${news.get(i).getTitle()}
```

Т.е. использовать переменную i из цикла. Однако, она все время = 0, независимо от итераций. Что делаю не так и как исправить?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете скриплеты `<% %>` вместе с expression language, что не верно. Переменная `i` не доступна в области видимости EL.

Используйте JSTL:

```
<c:forEach begin="0" end="2" varStatus="loop">
  ${news.get(loop.index).getTitle()}
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<% for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { %>
<jsp:include page="main_news.jsp"></jsp:include> 
<% } %>
```